# Irreducible polynomials and affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be any field, and let $f,g\in k[x,y]$ be two irreducible polynomials such
that $g$ is not divisible by $f$. Prove that $V(f,g)\subseteq A_k^2$ is finite.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 13):

No need to consider $f,g$ irreducible polynomials, it's enough to assume $\gcd(f,g)=1$. Then $\gcd(f,g)=1$ in $K(X)[Y]$, and therefore there exist $u,v\in K(X)[Y]$ such that $1=uf+vg$. In order to clear the denominators we can find a polynomial $w\in K[X]$ such that $wu,wv\in K[X,Y]$. From $w=(wu)f+(wv)g$ it's obvious that $f(a,b)=g(a,b)=0$ implies $w(a)=0$ and since $w$ has only finitely many roots in $K$ we are done.

Comment: @user26857 Hi. I can see why the $x$-coordinate has a finite number of roots in $(f,g)$ of $\mathbb{A}^2$, but how are you able to conclude that the $y$-coordinate is also finite?

Comment: @jm.byrnes, you do the same thing with the variables interchanged, of course...

Comment: How did you prove that "$\gcd(f,g)=1$. Then $\gcd(f,g)=1$ in $K(X)[Y]$"?

Comment: Use Gauss' lemma (Theorem 2.1 from https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210APage/handouts/gausslemma.pdf). Basically, any positive-degree factor of f in K(X)[Y] leads to a positive-degree factor of f in K[X, Y].