# If $F,G \in k[X,Y]$ have no common factors, then $V(F,G)$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, proof-explanation

Let $k$ be a field and suppose $F,G$ do not have common factors in $k[X,Y]$.

Then $V(F,G) = \{P \in k^2\mid F(P) = 0 = G(P)\}$ is finite.

The proof my book provides does the following:

Because $F,G$ have no common factors in $k[X,Y] = k[X][Y]$, they don't have common factors in $k(X)[Y]$ (here $k(X)$ is the fraction field of $k[X]$). Because $k(X)[Y]$ is a PID, we have

$$(F,G) = 1$$ in $k(X)[Y]$

Questions:

> (1) I can see that if $F,G$ have no **non-constant** common factors in
>   $k[X,Y] = k[X][Y]$, they don't have common non-constant factors in
>   $k(X)[Y]$. Shouldn't this be included in the proof?
>
> (2) Why does it follow that $(F,G) = 1?$ I know that a gcd always
>   exists in a PID.

Comment: Do you mean **non-constant** in $k[X,Y]$ or in $k[X][Y]$? conventionally a constant in the former is some $c \in k$ but in the latter is any polynomial $f \in k[X]$.  Saying there are no common factors in $k[X,Y]$ implies there are no nonconstant common factors in $k[X][Y]$

Comment: No common factors in $k[X,Y]$. But if there is a common constant factor in $k(X)[Y]$ that can violate that the gcd is 1 right?

Comment: Two related posts: [Irreducible polynomials and affine variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384740/irreducible-polynomials-and-affine-variety) and [Bezout in $\mathbb C [x,y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066750/bezout-in-mathbb-c-x-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant in $k(X)[Y]$ is an element of $k(X)$ and hence a unit.  Units are *excluded* from the definition of factor because they divide everything.  Greatest Common Divisors and Least Common Multiples are only meaningfully defined up to unit multiples.  With this in mind, knowing that $F,G$ have no common factors in $k(X)[Y]$, you know that their $GCD$ is $1$.  In a PID, the GCD of two elements generates their ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The first claim (1) is Gauss' lemma. Second claim follows from the fact $(F,G)$ is an ideal, and it must be principal. It's generator is the gcd of $F$ and $G$, which is in this case $1$ because we assumed $F$ and $G$ have no common factors in $\mathbb k[X,Y]$ and by Gauss' lemma this transfers to $\mathbb k(X)[Y]$.

Comment: But doesn't Gauss lemma say anything about non-constant common factors (the non-constant part is left out here).

Comment: @Math_QED I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Perhaps the first section of [these](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) notes helps.